# Problems with QueryDSL count() over ID column

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, querydsl

I have this Entity, which maps the relationship between a User and a Workgroup

```
package it.prisma.dal.dao.entities.accounting;

import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "UserAccount_has_Workgroup")
public class UserAccountHasWorkgroup implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6537213525312531347L;


    private UserAccountHasWorkgroupId id;
    private UserAccount userAccountByUserAccountId;
    private WorkgroupPrivilege workgroupPrivilege;
    private UserAccount userAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId;
    private Workgroup workgroup;
    private boolean approved;


    public UserAccountHasWorkgroup() {
    }

    public UserAccountHasWorkgroup(UserAccountHasWorkgroupId id,
            UserAccount userAccountByUserAccountId,
            UserAccount userAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId,
            Workgroup workgroup, boolean approved) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userAccountByUserAccountId = userAccountByUserAccountId;
        this.userAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId = userAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId;
        this.workgroup = workgroup;
        this.approved = approved;
    }

    public UserAccountHasWorkgroup(UserAccountHasWorkgroupId id,
            UserAccount userAccountByUserAccountId,
            WorkgroupPrivilege workgroupPrivilege,
            UserAccount userAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId,
            Workgroup workgroup, boolean approved) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userAccountByUserAccountId = userAccountByUserAccountId;
        this.workgroupPrivilege = workgroupPrivilege;
        this.userAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId = userAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId;
        this.workgroup = workgroup;
        this.approved = approved;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "userAccountId", column = @Column(name = "userAccountID", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "workgroupId", column = @Column(name = "workgroupID", nullable = false)) })
    public UserAccountHasWorkgroupId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(UserAccountHasWorkgroupId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userAccountID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public UserAccount getUserAccountByUserAccountId() {
        return this.userAccountByUserAccountId;
    }

    public void setUserAccountByUserAccountId(
            UserAccount userAccountByUserAccountId) {
        this.userAccountByUserAccountId = userAccountByUserAccountId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "workgroupPrivilegeID")
    public WorkgroupPrivilege getWorkgroupPrivilege() {
        return this.workgroupPrivilege;
    }

    public void setWorkgroupPrivilege(WorkgroupPrivilege workgroupPrivilege) {
        this.workgroupPrivilege = workgroupPrivilege;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "approvedBy_userAccountID", nullable = false)
    public UserAccount getUserAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId() {
        return this.userAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId;
    }

    public void setUserAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId(
            UserAccount userAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId) {
        this.userAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId = userAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "workgroupID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Workgroup getWorkgroup() {
        return this.workgroup;
    }

    public void setWorkgroup(Workgroup workgroup) {
        this.workgroup = workgroup;
    }

    @Column(name = "approved", columnDefinition = "bit", nullable = false)
    public boolean isApproved() {
        return this.approved;
    }

    public void setApproved(boolean approved) {
        this.approved = approved;
    }

}
```

Now I'd like to use QueryDSL to get the count of the tuples. In particular I have this QueryDSL query

```
JPAQuery query =  new JPAQuery(getEntityManager()).from(userAccountHasWorkgroup)
                .where(userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId.id
                        .eq(userAccountId));
```

where `userAccountHasWorkgroup` is the QueryDSL's `QUserAccountHasWorkgroup` instance. As you can see the query is run over a field which is part of the Key of the Entity.
The above query is translated in the following JPA query

```
select userAccountHasWorkgroup
from UserAccountHasWorkgroup userAccountHasWorkgroup
where userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId.id = ?1
```

I try to run the code:

```
query.count()
```

The problem is that this code raises the following exception

http://pastebin.com/C9kEHqHp

The entity correctly refers to the table in the DB.

What could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Try `query.singleResult(<entityName>.<columnName>.count())`